# Writing a dockerfile to export file to database on command run

Tags: docker

I was just trying out a docker tutorial on creating a custom image , the tutorial is **[THIS](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)** one.

So basically what i did was just executed the following command:

```
$ docker pull training/sinatra
```

There are two ways of building your Dockerfile, I choose using a custom Dockerfile , So, I created a new directory and navigated inside it and created a text file, like so.

```
$ mkdir sinatra
$ cd sinatra
$ touch Dockerfile
```

I edited the docker file to look like below:

```
# This is a comment
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Kate Smith <ksmith@example.com>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev
RUN gem install sinatra
```

Now I executed the build command,

```
$ docker build -t ouruser/sinatra:v2 .
```

Now if I run,

```
$ docker images
```

I will get my custom image in the results. Well now I have a new challenge , I need to create an image of a post postgresql and I have a file called map.osm , i need to do the following now:

> Add a parameter to the image (in the Dockerfile), so when a user runs
>   the image with 'docker run ... map.osm' the map gets imported into the
>   PostGIS database inside the image.

I am really confused , How do I code a dockerfile such that when a command is run a certain file will be imported into the database ?

Comment: I am offering a bounty of 50 points and a sack of gold coins , incase this question is not attactive to anyone yet ! thanks (the 50 points are for real !!)

Comment: You're not actually offering a bounty yet, and you can't until two days from when you post the question.  Claiming to offer a bounty beforehand will probably have the opposite effect of the one intended.

Comment: @larsks Ohh ! ok , i'll offer it in 2 days then .. i did't mean to hurt anybodys sentiments . TY

Comment: `Add a parameter to the image (in the Dockerfile), so when a user runs the image with 'docker run ... map.osm' the map gets imported into the PostGIS database inside the image.` - where is this from?

Comment: @manojlds thats something i need to do , does it make sufficient sense , basically i just need to export a file `map.osm` to the postgresql database when a command is executed , the logic of the `map.osm` file being exported to the postgresql database needs to be written in the Dockerfile .

Comment: You're going to run Ruby and a database in the same image?

Comment: @HatemJaber not sure ! u can suggest a better way !

Comment: The point of using docker is so that you can separate parts of the applications into separate containers. Each container runs in a separate process and you would do some kind of linking between containers to have them communicate with each other. You can have a Ruby, MySQL, etc... containers that would be dedicated for a specific task.

Comment: @HatemJaber Thanks extremely insightful !

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not the *proper* way to use docker.  Docker is meant to run one application by itself so that you have more control over which applications get updated as well as better management of the software they are using (e.g. this code uses python 3, this uses python 2, ect).

With that said if you want to accomplish this you will need to understand how Docker works.

Each time you initialize a container from an image it creates a new version of it.  Because of this it will initialize your DB or program without settings or data applied.

If you want your database to start, have a login and import data then you will want to create a dockerentrypoint.sh file and script all of that.

When docker containers start they run the process in the foreground and not the background.  So once your database starts it will be running in the foreground of your container and you will not be able to execute additional tasks unless you send it to the background. If you do this you will need to ensure you pull that task back to the foreground when you are done running any subtasks.  this is because once a process completes the container shuts down.  If you want your container to stay daemonized you will need to pull your db process back to the foreground before you exit your script.

**Solution:** Build a custom bash script to init the db and import the db.  Set this script as your ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile.